# Probability & Combination. N pairs of shoes in closet.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, combinatorial-game-theory

7 pairs of shoes (i.e., 14 shoes) are in a closet. 4 persons whose shoes are among the 7 pairs randomly selected 2 shoes each from the closet. 
What is the probability that exactly 2 persons selected their pairs of shoes?

**My attempt:**

$1\frac{12}{13}\frac{10}{12}\frac{8}{11}$

is the P(of no pairs)

**Another attempt:**

$\frac{\:2!}{0!\:\cdot \left(2\:-\:0\right)!}\: \cdot  \frac{\:14!}{5!\:\cdot \left(14\:-\:5\right)!}\:$ = Possible outcomes for the ith
person selects their own pair of shoes

Comment: Do the persons have common sense enough here to select a shoe for left foot and one for right foot?

Comment: @drhab They do not have common sense, they pick at random.

Comment: These attempts don't make much sense to me.  You ought to start by figuring out how many ways there are for the people to choose shoes.  Then figure out the ways for exactly two of them to choose the right shoes.    How many ways are there to choose the people who choose the right shoes?  How many ways for them to choose the correct shoes?  How many ways for the other two to choose the wrong shoes?  Divide the second number by the first to get the probability.

Comment: The first "attempt" looks like you grab four shoes total and you asked the probability that all shoes came from different pairs.  While that is a good probability problem and one that is commonly taught early on (see the "birthday problem"), it is completely unrelated to the current problem at hand.  The second attempt is the number of ways of picking seven shoes out of sixteen such that among the chosen shoes two of them are the shoes for Mr. A.  This also is unfortunately far from the intended problem and the numbers are off from what we want.

Answer (score 1):

We have $14$ shoes in the closet and $4$ people who pick $2$ shoes each. Our $\Omega$ can be seen as $\Omega = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 ): x_i \in \mathcal P_2(\{1,...,14\}, x_i \cap x_j = \emptyset$ for $  i \neq j$, and $ i,j \in \{1,...,4\} \} $

$\mathcal P_2(X)$ denote set of subsets $A$ of $X$, such that $|A| = 2$.

$x_i$ is the pair of shoes that $i'$th person pick.

That is, we have $|\Omega| = {14 \choose 2}{12 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2} $

Now, we look at event $E$ - exactly 2 people select their pair of shoes.

We have ${4 \choose 2}$ ways to choose those people, and for every choice the rest is symetrical, so let's figure out the answer for case: $1,2$ (the order as in $\Omega$) person pick their pair of shoes, whereas $3,4$ doesn't pick their pair of shoes. There is simply $1$ way for person $1,2$ to pick their pair. So now, we're left with $10$ shoes (exactly $5$ pairs), and $2$ people to choose $2$ shoes each (in those $10$ shoes there are pairs of person $3$ and $4$). It will be easier, to count ways when at least one of them do select their pair. By Inclusion-Exlusion, from all possible ways ${10\choose 2}{8\choose 2}$, we need to substract $2 {8 \choose 2} - 1$ (where ${8 \choose 2}$ is the ways to choose any $2$ shoes out of $8$ shoes, when one person already selected his pair (we count it double, because it can be either person $1$ or $2$), and that $-1$ is due to possibility that both $1,2$ choose their pair.)

So that $|E| = {4 \choose 2}( {10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2} - 2{8 \choose 2} + 1)$

And we have $\mathbb P(E) = \frac{{4 \choose 2}( {10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2} - 2{8 \choose 2} + 1)}{{14 \choose 2}{12 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Number the persons with $1,2,3,4$.

Let $A,B,C,D$ denote the events that persons $1,2,3$ and $4$ respectively
picks his own shoes.

Then by symmetry it is clear that the probability that exactly $2$
persons pick their own shoes is: $$\binom{4}{2}P\left(A\cap B\cap C^{\complement}\cap D^{\complement}\right)$$

Here: $$P\left(A\cap B\cap C^{\complement}\cap D^{\complement}\right)=P\left(A\right)P\left(B\mid A\right)P\left(C^{\complement}\cap D^{\complement}\mid A\cap B\right)$$

and: $$P\left(C^{\complement}\cap D^{\complement}\mid A\cap B\right)=1-P\left(C\cup D\mid A\cap B\right)=$$$$1-P\left(C\mid A\cap B\right)-P\left(D\mid A\cap B\right)+P\left(C\cap D\mid A\cap B\right)=$$$$1-2P\left(C\mid A\cap B\right)+P\left(C\mid A\cap B\right)P\left(D\mid A\cap B\cap C\right)$$

---

Can you find $P\left(A\right),P\left(B\mid A\right),P\left(C\mid A\cap B\right)$
and $P\left(D\mid A\cap B\cap C\right)$ yourself?